How can i return a HashMap from my Repository Interface SpringBoot
I want to return a HashMap with the number of a property (String) as the key and a Long as the value.
But I tried many ways but still I am stuck.
@Repository
public interface ICBT_Repository_Owner extends JpaRepository<PropietarioModel, Long> {


    @Query(value = "SELECT new map(p.numProperty, p.idPropietario) FROM PropietarioModel p", nativeQuery = false)
    HashMap<String, Long> findProperties();

    @Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(p.numProperty) FROM PropietarioModel p", nativeQuery = false)
    Long countProperties();
}

This is the code but i don't know what to do.

First of all thing to rename your repository name to follow the convention as described here
Change the return type of the query to List<Object[]>
@Repository
public interface ICBT_Repository_Owner extends JpaRepository<PropietarioModel, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p.numProperty, COUNT(p.idPropietario) FROM PropietarioModel p GROUP BY p.numProperty")
    List<Object[]> findProperties();
}

You can process the List<Object[]> into a HashMap<String, Long>:
@Service
public class PropertyService {

    @Autowired
    private ICBT_Repository_Owner repositoryOwner;

    public HashMap<String, Long> getProperties() {
        List<Object[]> results = repositoryOwner.findProperties();
        HashMap<String, Long> propertiesMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Object[] result : results) {
            String numProperty = (String) result[0];
            Long count = (Long) result[1];
            propertiesMap.put(numProperty, count);
        }

        return propertiesMap;
    }
}


Another approach to derive at the requirement,
Using a Custom DTO
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PropertyDTO {
    private String numProperty;
    private Long idPropietario;
}

Modify the repository,
@Repository
public interface ICBT_Repository_Owner extends JpaRepository<PropietarioModel, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT new com.yourpackage.PropertyDTO(p.numProperty, p.idPropietario) FROM PropietarioModel p")
    List<PropertyDTO> findPropertiesAsDTO();

    default HashMap<String, Long> findProperties() {
        List<PropertyDTO> results = findPropertiesAsDTO();
        HashMap<String, Long> propertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (PropertyDTO dto : results) {
            propertiesMap.put(dto.getNumProperty(), dto.getIdPropietario());
        }
        return propertiesMap;
    }
}

